# How to insert data from a many to many relationship from typeorm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeorm

If I'm the user Andrés, and I want to create a new project with my coworkers José, Maria and Martin. So, I have this logic:

A project has a lot users, like this:

[image]

And a user has a lot projects, like this:

[image]

// This file will represent that "new project", in this case, it needs a title, a name, a body, and it has a relation many to many with the entity user.

```
import {
    Entity,
    BaseEntity,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    Column,
    ManyToMany,
    JoinTable
} from "typeorm";

import { User } from "./User";

@Entity()
export class Matrix extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column("varchar", { length: 100 })
    title: string;

    @Column("varchar", { length: 255 })
    name: string;

    @Column("json", { nullable: true })
    body: object;

    @ManyToMany(() => User)
    @JoinTable({ name: "coworkers" })
    coworkers: User[];
}
```

// This user entity only has the basic info of every normal user...

```
import * as bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import {
    Entity,
    BaseEntity,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    Column,
    BeforeInsert
} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column("varchar", { length: 255 })
    name: string;

    @Column("varchar", { length: 255 })
    lastname: string;

    @Column("varchar", { length: 255, unique: true })
    email: string;

    @Column("text")
    password: string;

    @Column({ default: false })
    confirmed: boolean;

    @BeforeInsert()
    async hashPassword() {
        this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10);
    }
}
```

So, if I want to create a new project called "Análisis empresas x" I use this query:

```
    const matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.coworkers = ["1", "2", "3"]; // Array of coworkers ids
    matrix.title = "Análisis empresas x"; // What name has the matrix.
    matrix.name = "Matrix d.o.f.a"; // What type of matrix is.
    await matrix.save();
```

That code create the matrix perfectly but the relation with user on the table "Coworkers" witch is "many to many" does not add anything...

This is the complete code I'm using [(code)](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/GestionEstrategicaOrganizacional/blob/master/server/src/modules/matrix/controller.ts)

This is the entity User [(code)](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/GestionEstrategicaOrganizacional/blob/master/server/src/entity/User.ts)

This is the entity Matrix [(code)](https://github.com/MontoyaAndres/GestionEstrategicaOrganizacional/blob/master/server/src/entity/Matrix.ts)

Please help :)

Comment: Coworkers is an array of User. You should provide User values in the array and not id.

Comment: @zenbeni can you give a example?

Comment: matrix.coworkers = [new User()];

Comment: [It could help you. please have a look.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54886350/9808302)